# What does slash equal in javascript do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently reviewing some Javascript code in a jQuery plug-in and came across this line of code:

```
duration /= 2;
```

It appears from other code that the duration variable is a numeric value.

Can someone explain exactly what that does with the slash equal?

Comment: In addition to the other answers, there is also +=, -=, and *=. They all do similar things, except instead of dividing by the right side of the expression, they add to / subtract from / multiply by the right side of the expression.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It divides your duration variable by 2.

```
duration = 4;
duration /= 2;  // duration now is 2
```

Comment: Right: it's effectively equivalent to `duration = duration / 2;`

Comment: Well duh, long day of reading code for me today I guess I will go watch TV now :)

Answer (score 14):

It's the equivalent of this:

```
duration = duration / 2;
```

You can do the same thing with the +, - and * operators, along with many others, as a shortcut:

```
var duration = 2;
duration += 2;  // now is 4
duration *= 2; // now is 8
duration -=4; // now is 4 again.
```

Answer (score 3):

That's two operations:

1. Division
2. Assignment

You've probably seen this with addition and subtraction before: `+=` or `-=`

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting this for further clarity:

You can do the same thing with the +, - and * operators, along with many others, as a shortcut:

```
var duration = 2; // declaring the variable "duration" and assigning it the value of 2
duration += 2;  // duration = duration + 2 // now duration is 4
duration *= 2; // duration = duration * 2 // now duration is 8
duration -=4; // duration = duration - 4 //now duration is 4 again
```